# Code customizing

Tags: development, column

I have a document library with a deadline column and a status column. If the deadline expires, the date will be red (see code). Now, additionally, when the task status is closed, the date should turn black again. Activity status is only open and closed.
How can i customize the Code? Thank you all!

```
{

   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "style": {
      "color": {
         "operator": "?",
         "operands": [
            {
               "operator": "<=",
               "operands": [
                  "[$Deadline]",
                  "@now"
               ]
            },
            "#ff0000",
            ""
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Many Greetings
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the JSON Formatting for your case:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "&&",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "!=",
              "operands": [
                "[$Status]",
                "closed"
              ]
            },
            {
              "operator": "<=",
              "operands": [
                "[$Deadline]",
                "@now"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "#ff0000",
        ""
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please mark as answer if it is the desired solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for that Code! sure that this Code works? when i press F5 it have the same "red"-Colour

Comment: that works for textfields but not for a dropdownlist right?!

Comment: It works for dropdown and date both.

Comment: Check the spelling and case of "closed" with your dropdown options. They should match. And your deadline should be a date column. Only then it will satisfy a condition with @now